# The requested URL /login was not found on this server.

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux

I am trying to enable SSL for port 4100 for an Amazon EC2 Instance. When I access the site https://test.example.com:4100/login, I get an error as follows - The requested URL /login was not found on this server. Can someone please help me?

I've modified **httpd.conf** as below -

```
 <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    NameVirtualHost *:4100
    Listen 4100
 </IfModule>
 <VirtualHost *:4100>
    ServerName test.example.com
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.example.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.example.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.example.com/fullchain.pem
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
 </VirtualHost>
```

**ssl.conf**

```
 Listen 443
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.example.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.example.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.example.com/fullchain.pem
 <VirtualHost>
```